# How to print solutions as a table in sagemath

Tags: sage

I define a function `f(N,F)` where `N` and `F` are both positive integer such that `gcd(N,F)=1`, `\mu(N)=-1` and `\mu(F) \neq 0`. Then I want to print `f(N,F)` for `N` and `F` less than `200` as a table in sagemath. I think I need to use a loop to give the values of `N` and `F`. But I don't know how to store these values and print the corresponding `f(N,F)` in a table.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this, and of course you didn't say what `f` was.  But Sage has a [built-in `table()` command](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/misc/sage/misc/table.html) which allows quite a bit of customization and which outputs appropriate to the context you are using Sage in.

So you need a list and you need a table.  To get the list, I'd use a filtered list comprehension.

```
L = [[(N,F),N+F] for N in [1..100] for F in [1..100] if moebius(N)==-1 and moebius(F)!=0 and gcd(N,F)==1]
```

Here are some references:

1. http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/prep/Programming.html#lists
2. http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/tutorial-programming-python.html#creating-lists-iii-list-comprehensions
3. http://more-sagemath-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/2009-01-01-SienaTutorials/Worksheet02-Lists.html#list-comprehensions

For the table, you can do lots of things.  `table()` works fine, but maybe you want something spruced up, like a header.  See [this example](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzzUbBViI7W8NNx09Tx03aLVUjLL1LwU8jMU4g21NMzNDCAiLihiGSmKeTmpyZllhZr-Gna2uoaKiTmpcCF3DQVbQ3AIunJKWCTbW0NY3m5ShKTclI1fHQyUhNTUovii_LLbaOVVMAKVJR0lFSA1qsoxWoCAIUjKCY=&lang=sage).

```
table(L,header_row=["$(N,F)$","$N+F$"])
```